# pl/sql procedure error issue

Tags: oracle, plsql

I'm trying to make a procedure in pl/sql but I can't. I have 2 tables, one has 100 names in it and the other has 100 surnames. I want to make a procedure that takes a random name and surname, and then I want to introduce that data into another table, but I get an error and I'm new to pl/sql and don't know what to do. Here is my code.

```
DROP TABLE grade
/
CREATE TABLE grade (grade CHAR(2))
/
INSERT INTO grade VALUES ('A1');
INSERT INTO grade VALUES ('A2');
INSERT INTO grade VALUES ('A3');
INSERT INTO grade VALUES ('A4');
INSERT INTO grade VALUES ('A5');
INSERT INTO grade VALUES ('A6');
INSERT INTO grade VALUES ('A7');
INSERT INTO grade VALUES ('B1');
INSERT INTO grade VALUES ('B2');
INSERT INTO grade VALUES ('B3');
INSERT INTO grade VALUES ('B4');
INSERT INTO grade VALUES ('B5');
INSERT INTO grade VALUES ('B6');
INSERT INTO grade VALUES ('B7');
commit;

set serveroutput on
DECLARE
v_contor INTEGER := 1;
v_nr NUMBER(10);
v_name VARCHAR2(20);
v_surname VARCHAR2(20);
v_year NUMBER(2);
v_grade VARCHAR2(20);
v_scholarship NUMBER(4);
v_nota NUMBER(2);

PROCEDURE insert_data IS

cursor c1 is
   select name from(select name from name
              order by dbms_ryeardom.value)
   where rownum =1;

cursor c2 is
   select surname from(select surname from surname
              order by dbms_ryeardom.value)
   where rownum =1;

cursor c3 is 
   select grade from(select grade from grade
              order by dbms_ryeardom.value)
   where rownum =1;

BEGIN

   v_nr := 124;
   WHILE v_contor <= 2000 LOOP
        open c1;
        open c2;
    open c3;
    LOOP
        fetch c1 into v_name;
        exit when c1%notfound;
        END loop;
    LOOP
        fetch c2 into v_surname;
        exit when c2%notfound;
        END loop;
    LOOP
        fetch c3 into v_grade;
        exit when c3%notfound;
        END loop;
    v_year := round(dbms_ryeardom.value(1,3));
    v_scholarship := round(dbms_ryeardom.value(250,450));
    INSERT INTO studenti VALUES (v_nr, INITCAP(v_name), v_surname, v_year, v_grade, v_scholarship, NULL);
        IF (v_year = 2) THEN
            v_nota := round(dbms_ryeardom.value(4,10));
            INSERT INTO note VALUES (v_nr, 21, v_nota, NULL);
        v_nota := round(dbms_ryeardom.value(4,10));
            INSERT INTO note VALUES (v_nr, 22, v_nota, NULL);
        v_nota := round(dbms_ryeardom.value(4,10));
            INSERT INTO note VALUES (v_nr, 23, v_nota, NULL);
    END if;
    IF (v_year = 3) THEN
        v_nota := round(dbms_ryeardom.value(4,10));
            INSERT INTO note VALUES (v_nr, 21, v_nota, NULL);
        v_nota := round(dbms_ryeardom.value(4,10));
            INSERT INTO note VALUES (v_nr, 22, v_nota, NULL);
        v_nota := round(dbms_ryeardom.value(4,10));
            INSERT INTO note VALUES (v_nr, 23, v_nota, NULL);
        v_nota := round(dbms_ryeardom.value(4,10));
            INSERT INTO note VALUES (v_nr, 24, v_nota, NULL);
        v_nota := round(dbms_ryeardom.value(4,10));
            INSERT INTO note VALUES (v_nr, 25, v_nota, NULL);
        v_nota := round(dbms_ryeardom.value(4,10));
            INSERT INTO note VALUES (v_nr, 26, v_nota, NULL);
        v_nota := round(dbms_ryeardom.value(4,10));
            INSERT INTO note VALUES (v_nr, 29, v_nota, NULL);
    END if;
        v_nr := v_nr + 1;
    v_contor := v_contor + 1;
    close c1;
    close c2;
    close c3;
    END loop;
END;
/
BEGIN
    insert_data;
END;
/
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: Encountered the symbol “end-of-file” when expecting one of the following: begin function pragma procedure

Comment: and i'm getting this error for all my procedures that i'm working on and don't know what to do. :(

Comment: If you want to create a procedure inside an anoymous PL/SQL block you need to remove the `/` after the `end;` of the procedure. If you want to create a standalone procedure then see user76ponic's answer. You also have several invalid select statements: e.g. `select name from name` or `select surname from surname`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name `SELECT name FROM name` is valid if you have a table called `name` which contains a column called `name`. Not particularly good practice to call them both the same thing but it is valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are declaring the procedure in a PL/SQL anonymous block and not in the SQL - this is not a problem but you are completing the declaration of the procedure and are not completing the declaration of the anonymous block.

An anonymous PL/SQL block has the format:

```
DECLARE
  ...
BEGIN
  ...
END;
/
```

The `PROCEDURE` declaration goes between the `DECLARE` and `BEGIN` clauses and has the form:

```
PROCEDURE name IS ... BEGIN ... END;
```

There is no trailing `/` at the end of the procedure declaration as `;` terminates a PL/SQL statement and `/` is used to terminate the outer-most PL/SQL block (indicating that you are returning to the SQL scope - and if you were nesting PL/SQL blocks then you would not use the '/' terminator on the inner blocks).

If you remove the first `/` from your code then it should get rid of the `end-of-file` error.

You should also declare the variables used in the procedure within the procedure and not in the containing PL/SQL anonymous block (i.e. between the procedure's `IS` and `BEGIN` clauses and not between the outer blocks `DECLARE` and the `PROCEDURE` statements).

If you want to declare the procedure in the SQL scope (and not in an anonymous block) then you need to use:

```
CREATE [OR REPLACE] PROCEDURE name IS ... BEGIN ... END;
/
```

*(The trailing `/` will be required in this instance as the statement will not be contained in a surrounding PL/SQL anonymous block and will be declared directly in the SQL scope so needs the `/` to indicate that the declaration of the procedure has concluded.)*

You also have an issue that your cursors contain the `order by dbms_ryeardom.value` which appears to be a typo for `order by dbms_random.value`.

There may also be an issue with repeatedly opening and closing the same cursors.

Comment: if I declare the variables within the procedure I have to declare them like this: v_nr NUMBER(10); or just v_nr NUMBER;

Comment: `v_nr NUMBER(10);` or this would allow you to mimic the datatype of the `NR_COLUMN` column in the `NOTE` table: `v_nr NOTE.NR_COLUMN%TYPE;`.

Answer (score -1):

First:

```
Create or replace procedure AS
```

not

```
procedure IS
```

Second:

U cannot declare

```
v_contor INTEGER := 1;
v_nr NUMBER(10);
v_name VARCHAR2(20);
v_surname VARCHAR2(20);
v_year NUMBER(2);
v_grade VARCHAR2(20);
v_scholarship NUMBER(4);
v_nota NUMBER(2);
```

and then creatin procedure. This declarations have to be inside procedure after 'AS'. I don't remember if in procedure u type lenght of value or not
f.e. v_r number; instead of v_r number(10);

try both ways:)

summa summarum - You procedure should start like this

```
create or replace PROCEDURE insert_data AS

v_grade VARCHAR2;
v_scholarship NUMBER;
v_nota NUMBER;
....
```

and about the end:

```
END;
/
BEGIN
    insert_data;
END;
/
```

change to

```
END;
/


BEGIN
    execute(insert_data);
END;
/
```

Comment: The procedure is being declared in an anonymous PL/SQL block and not in the SQL scope so `CREATE OR REPLACE` is not required here.